# Error "could not convert string to float: 'INLAND'"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm doing a project on housing price prediction using machine learning, and want to submit it to a private firm for an application.

I am working in the Jupiter notebook for this project, but I am unable to fix the bugs regarding conversion for word strings to numerical data

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(X,
                                              Y,
                                             test_size=0.2,
                                               random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
independent_scalar = StandardScaler()
X_train = independent_scalar.fit_transform (X_train) #fit and transform
X_test = independent_scalar.transform (X_test) # only transform
print(X_train)
```

I am expecting a training set data to be completely numerical

Comment: Could you show us atleast a link or the first few rows of the dataset you are using. Also where is the error occurring.

Comment: Do you think that having "please help me to fix this" in your title adds something to the title's descriptive quality?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dataset you have has strings in it. StandardScaler() takes only numerical data and standardize the values.

To convert the text into numerical data, you can check out functions in `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`. Depending on your data, you could check out the functions which suits best. `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer` are the most common vectorizers used. `CountVectorizer` is based on Bag of Words algorithm and `TfidfVectorizer` is based of TF-IDF.

To know which function to use, it would be easier if we know what the dataset looks like.